# Applying Dilworth's theorem to 50 intervals in R

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> **Problem :** Prove that among any 50 intervals **R**, one can either find 8 disjoint intervals or 8 intervals having a common point.

I think it is quite obvious I need to apply Dilworth's theorem to my problem.

Let's denote the set of intervals by $I = \{I_1, I_2,... , I_n \}$. Define the partial order $\preceq$ on $I$ so that $I_i \preceq I_j$ if and only if one of the following holds:

1. $I_i = I_j$
2. $I_i \cap I_j = \varnothing$ and $I_i$ is to the left of $I_j$, i.e.$\forall x \in I_i$ $\forall y \in I_j $ we have $x < y$.

$(I, \preceq)$ is a poset.

By Dilworth’s theorem, we get that $(I, \preceq)$  has either a chain of size $n$ or an antichain of size $\sqrt n$. In the former case, we get $\sqrt n$ pairwise disjoint intervals. In the latter case, we have a set of $\sqrt n$ intervals $I'$ whose pairwise intersection is non-empty.

From there I don't really know what would be the next logical step.

Comment: You suggested partial order is not, in fact, a partial order because it isn't antisymmetric.  Consider two disjoint intervals.

Comment: It seems your condition 1 is redundant. I suspect that you meant $I_i = I_j$. Then the argument seems fine. It only misses this fact: if any two intervals intersect, then all of them intersect (which is easy to prove: consider the leftmost right end and the rightmost left end of the intervals).

Comment: @zhoraster Hi you are right it's $I_i = I_j$ for the first criteria. I am trying to understand the problem, English is not my language and the problem is written in English. What exactly is an interval of **R**?

Comment: Interval is interval. $[a,b]$, $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$, or $(a,b]$.

Comment: "chain or size $n$ or antichain of size $\sqrt(n)$" looks like a typo; I think you mean chain of size $\sqrt(n)$. What is the exact statement of Dilworth's theorem?